# Filter JSON based on selected dropdown option

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file with a list of countries which has 2 keys: "name" and "areacode". I have dropdown with a list of options that has a value attr witch is the same as the "name" key in the JSON file.

Long story short: I want to display the "areacode" value in the json file when the selected option in the dropdown matches the "name" value in the JSON file

[image: Screenshot]

**UPDATE**

I have pasted the code here: http://codepen.io/sarfehjou/pen/RpKMWE

The only difference is that in my solution I have to get the JSON file by a url

**HTML**

```
  <select>
   <option value="Afghanistan GLOBAL">Afghanistan GLOBAL</option>
   <option value="Albenter code hereania">Albania</option>
   <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
   <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
   <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
 </select>
```

**Script**

```
    var list = {
    "countries": [
        {
            "name": "Afghanistan GLOBAL",
            "areacode": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Albania",
            "areacode": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Algeria",
            "areacode": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "American Samoa",
            "areacode": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Andorra",
            "areacode": ""
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: please add all relevant data **in text form** to the question. you may have a look here, too [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague as already established, i.e. not sure what you need to do with area code and stuff? anyway this is what i could work out:

basically added an event listener on the select and whenever you change it, looks up the value from list (the list can be from the server or cached).

Have a look, if you get more ideas asks some more.

```js
    var list = {
    "countries": [
        {
            "name": "Afghanistan GLOBAL",
            "areacode": "8787"
        },
        {
            "name": "Albania",
            "areacode": "446"
        },
        {
            "name": "Algeria",
            "areacode": "212"
        },
        {
            "name": "American Samoa",
            "areacode": "767"
        },
        {
            "name": "Andorra",
            "areacode": "5454"
        }
      ]
    }
    
    var countrySelect = document.getElementById('countrySelect');
    
    countrySelect.addEventListener('change', function(e)  {
      console.log(this.value);
      console.log(findAreaCode(this.value));
    });
    
    function findAreaCode(name) {
      var resultItems = list.countries.filter(function(currentItem) {
        return currentItem.name == name;
      })
      console.log(resultItems[0]);
      
      return resultItems[0]? resultItems[0].areacode: 'N/A';
    }
```

```html
 <select id="countrySelect">
   <option value="Afghanistan GLOBAL">Afghanistan GLOBAL</option>
   <option value="Albenter code hereania">Albania</option>
   <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
   <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
   <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: glad could decipher...welcome to stackoverflow, accept the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

I have pasted the code her: http://codepen.io/sarfehjou/pen/RpKMWE

The only different is that in my solution I have to get the json file by a url

```
  <select>
   <option value="Afghanistan GLOBAL">Afghanistan GLOBAL</option>
   <option value="Albenter code hereania">Albania</option>
   <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
   <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
   <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
 </select> 

    var list = {
    "countries": [
        {
            "name": "Afghanistan GLOBAL",
            "areacode": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Albania",
            "areacode": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Algeria",
            "areacode": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "American Samoa",
            "areacode": ""
        },
        {
            "name": "Andorra",
            "areacode": ""
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Delete this, I have added it in the question. You might get negative rating otherwise.

Comment: i don't understand, what did you add in the question? and what should I delete?

Comment: The code you added above is a part of the question, correct? I added the thing you posted above in the question so that you can delete this answer post...

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can do this,

```
$.getJSON("http://api/somejsonfile/",function(data){
    // Initializing an empty array
    var options=[];
    // Running a loop on the response JSON and adding the options to a string array
    $.each(data.countries,function(id,eachcountry){
        options.push("<option value='"+eachcountry.areacode+"'>"+eachcountry.name+"</option>");
    });
    // Joining the string and replacing it inside the select element 
    $(".dropdown").html(options.join(""));
});
```

This is a rough implementation so there might be some syntactical issues!!

Adding a simple example

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// This is a sample country code JSON from Github
$.getJSON("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Goles/3196253/raw/9ca4e7e62ea5ad935bb3580dc0a07d9df033b451/CountryCodes.json",function(data){
     // Initializing an empty array
     var options=[];
     // Running a loop on the response JSON and adding the options to a string array
     $.each(data,function(id,eachcountry){
      options.push("<option value='"+eachcountry.dial_code+"'>"+eachcountry.name+"</option>");
     });
     // Joining the string and replacing it inside the select element 
     $(".dropdown").html(options.join(""));
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dropdown">
  <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```